# Preloading NodeJS Module in NextJs

Tags: node.js, next.js, preload

I have a next js application and I want to preload a Node JS module while starting
next js application

I am using below script to pre-load a module in next js

(please note -r option , tried to use -r from node ecosystem)

But it is not working and it says - Unknown or unexpected option: -r

```
"dev": "next -r 'module' dev"
```

Can anybody please help in how to preload a nodejs module in next js app ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
node --require module node_modules/next/dist/bin/next dev
```